# Arduino mini bluetooth module communicating with an Android device without using an app?

Tags: arduino, bluetooth

Is there a way to communicate between arduino device  and the android device through the bluetooth?

I know it is and for that is used some `pfodApp`, but what if I want to make my own application, without a need of standalone `pfodApp`. Do you know if there is anything like `pfod` library for Java/Android? Which would allow me to pair and communicate with the arduino?

Check this: [pfodApp](http://www.forward.com.au/pfod/index.html)

Comment: If you want native android libraries, it's simply serial over bluetooth. Android supports the pairing like normal, the rest is a standard Bluetooth serial library. Google "Arduino android bluetooth library" for hundreds of examples.

Comment: Super, thank you. I thought that it requires something special, since it is arduino...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want native android libraries, it's simply serial over bluetooth. Android supports the pairing like normal, the rest is a standard Bluetooth serial library. Google "Arduino android bluetooth library" for hundreds of examples.

The only thing that pdof does is a set of standard protocols of communication in a neat package. Depending on the complexity of your project, creating your own serial message might be easier or quicker.